# Is $Col(A)=Col(A^k)$? for positive semidefinite $A$?

Tags: matrices

$Col(A)$ denotes the column space of $A$

I was able to show this for $k=2$, but having a hard time showing it for other integer $k$.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: spectral theorem (assuming positive semi definite implies symmetric in this context).

Comment: Yes, it does imply symmetric.

Comment: Do you see how the spectral theorem is useful here?

Comment: Yes very useful, but I still am working on how to use the idea.

Comment: if you can make it into an answer, post it as an answer to your question. If you can get part of the way there, edit it into your original question. Formatting in comments is hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have proved it for $k=2$, then you are finished.

Let's assume you have proved $\def\C{\operatorname{Col}}\C(A)=\C(A^2)$. Then $$\C(A)=\C(A^2)=\C(A^4)=\C(A^8)=\dotsb$$
But $\C(A^m)\supseteq\C(A^n)$ if $m\le n$.

Comment: That is amazing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the spectral theorem, we have the following:

For any $k$, Col$(A)$ is the span of the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues. These eigenvectors are the same for all $k \geq 1$, since $\lambda^k=0\implies \lambda =0$.

Comment: So this must true for any symmetric $A$ then? No need for the positive semi-definite condition??

Comment: That's correct! This is also true for any $A$ that is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.